# What is the difference between logical and iterative set

Tags: logic, foundations, higher-order-logic

Saphiro in his "foundations without foundationalism: a case for second-order logic" defends second-order logic by claiming that talking about subsets of domain is not problematic in case of SOL. He defends it because before in the past sets theories proven to be inconsistent (Russel's paradox) but he claims that logical sets are not the same as iterative (ZFC) sets. Logical set has to be perceived as Boole sets which complements are sets them selves. Because of that they somehow should be free of contradictions and easier to work with. He didn't prove in any way how Boole set theory is not contradictory. He didn't also said what is aforementioned Boole set. So what is this set and why is it less problematic?

Comment: Could you please give a page number for the material you are referring to?

Comment: @CarlMummert . it is **Ch.1.3 Sets and properties** and specifically page 18-on, where Shapiro draws a distinction between "*iterative sense* of'set'"  (Cantor, Zermelo, ... and axiomatic s-t) and "The logical notion of set, on the other hand, always refers to a domain fixed by context. [...] In every context, logical sets exemplify what may be called a *Boolean* 
structure."

Comment: @CarlMummert I do not understand what it this boolean structure and what is changed by fixed context. I feel like his explanation is missing some hard mathematical facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think, to start with, of logical sets (in a given context) as all being subsets of a fixed universe of discourse, a universe of  non-sets (numbers or whatever).

There's a useful brief discussion of whether this limited conception of sets is really enough for second order logic in the final chapter on higher-order logics in the Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Math and Logic (see pp. 796-797).

As the Handbook essay in fact notes, Shapiro in fact later modified his view, in a paper you can download here http://www.accionfilosofica.com/misc/1214145300crs.pdf

Comment: Thank you, the paper was really enlightening. Before reading it I supposed that there must be some theory and axiomatization of 'logical set' but what author proposes is that we treat 'logical set' as primitive notion that does not need explaining. Because of such state of SOL it is why others call is set theory in disguise and say that SOL 'claims too much'.